# Confused about Valgrind errors after deleting off heap

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *val = new int;
    *val = 12;
    std::cout << *val << std::endl;
    delete &val;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run Valgrind on this, I get the following error:

```
SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 8 from 8)

1 errors in context 1 of 3:
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
    at 0x1000ABB6D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:533)
    by 0x100000D1E: main (pointers.cpp:8)
  Address 0x1048a09f0 is on thread 1's stack
  in frame #1, created by main (pointers.cpp:4)
```

What is wrong with how I am deleting `val`?

Comment: change `delete &val;` to `delete val;`

Comment: You call `delete` with the name of the pointer, not the address of the pointer.

Comment: you should be calling delete with just the variable name `val` instead of `&val`

Comment: @NathanOliver: The operand should be an expression with pointer type.  Whether it was once a variable name, pointer arithmetic, result of a function call, or whatever, does not matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `invalid free()` error if you try to free invalid memory.

```
delete &val;
```

here you are trying to delete address of `val`, rather than the memory `val` points to, which is wrong.
Try as below instead.

```
delete val;
```